# Морфология в полнотекстовом поиске MySQL

Tags: mysql, полнотекстовый-поиск, match, морфология

Часто встречаю упоминания, что полнотекстовый поиск MySQL работает с учётом морфологии. На практике этого добиться не получилось.

Создаю таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE `search_index` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` text,
  `tags` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`,`text`,`tags`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Заполняю данными. Делю запрос

```
select * from search_index where match(title,text,tags) against('стул');
```

Получаю N записей. Делю запрос

```
select * from search_index where match(title,text,tags) against('стулья');
```

Получаю 0 записей.

То же самое с английским языком. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL не поддерживает морфологию, при поиске и индексации текст разбивается на токены, которые по сути являются словами текста без какого-либо преобразования. Англоязычные мануалы предлагают использовать wildcard * для поиска по окончаниям. Т.е. при поиске по "apple*" будет находится "apples". Но для 
русского это не подходит.

Для поиска с учетом русского языка нужно индексировать текст с нормализованными токенами. Для этого добавить специальную колонку в таблицу и добавить для нее поисковый индекс, а при изменении текста документа сохранять в нее нормализованный текст. Соответственно поисковый запрос тоже нужно нормализовать.

Нормализация с использованием словаря - https://github.com/cijic/phpmorphy.
Нормализация с помощью стемминга - https://github.com/wamania/php-stemmer.